# Why is my program calculating the compound interest twice

Tags: python

I want to calculate the time it takes for the compound interest to reach a certain goal by using Pn=(1+i)Pn−1.
What I have done is:

```
def my_saving_plan(P0,i,goal):
    P = [P0]
    years = 0
    for n in range(0,10000):
        if P[n] < goal: 
            P.append((1+i)*P[n-1])
            years += 1
            print(P)
        elif P[n] >= goal:
            return years
print(my_saving_plan(1000, 0.07, 2000))
```

But What I get from that is the number of compound interest twice. So for this example what I get is:

```
    [1000, 1070.0, 1070.0, 1144.9, 1144.9, 1225.0430000000001, 
1225.0430000000001, 1310.7960100000003, 1310.7960100000003, 
1402.5517307000005, 1402.5517307000005, 1500.7303518490005, 
1500.7303518490005, 1605.7814764784307, 1605.7814764784307,
 1718.186179831921, 1718.186179831921, 1838.4592124201556, 
1838.4592124201556, 1967.1513572895667, 1967.1513572895667, 
2104.8519522998363]
    21
```

Also I was wondering if there is a way to use a while loop instead of putting a ridiculous number in the for loop.

Comment: That's a fun one. Still too easy to debug for an upvote, though.

Comment: You have an off-by-one error in your `append` line. `n` is already the last element, so you don't need `n-1`. You could also use `while P[-1] < goal` instead of `for`. Index `-1` refers to the last element. You don't need `n` at all.

Comment: Check your iteration for example n = 1. Your P has already two elements P[0] and P[1]. In line 6 you append (1 + i) * P[n - 1] = (1 + i) * P[0] which is the same as you already appended in the step before.

Comment: A_P, I was trying not to use the while loop because because I did not know how to specify `n` in the formula, but thanks I understand now!

Comment: Thanks Alex, I understood it now! I think I was to focused on the formula and not on the algorithm

Comment: @MiroFeliciano See my answer for how to use `while` correctly here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might as well turn my comment into an answer:

```
def my_saving_plan(P0,i,goal):
    P = [P0]
    while P[-1] < goal:
        P.append((1+i)*P[-1])
        print(P)
    return len(P) - 1

print(my_saving_plan(1000, 0.07, 2000))
```

From my comment:
You have an off-by-one error in your append line. `n` is already the last element, and using `n-1` will be one behind that, thus causing duplication.

You could also use `while P[-1] < goal` instead of `for`. Index `-1` always refers to the last element. You don't need `n` or `years` at all.

Comment: Don't forget an explanation

Comment: @KellyBundy Added a note about why `n-1` causes duplication.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was already going to ask why the P[-1] doesn't change. But what I get from this code is 12, while the answer should be 11

Comment: @MiroFeliciano What do you mean `P[-1]` doesn't change? It will always refer to the element before `P[0]` (in a cyclic fashion), so always refers to the last element. And sorry, I should return `len(P)-1`.

Comment: Nvm, I understand now. Why must the return be for len(P)-1? Is it because P already stores the first value?

Comment: Still doesn't really explain what caused the duplication, though, i.e., the real origin story is missing. But I explained it myself now...

Answer (score 2):

You are always refering to an element one behind where you think you are.

This is the corrected code:

```py
def my_saving_plan(P0, i, goal):
    P = [P0]
    years = 0
    for n in range(0, 10000):
        if P[n] < goal: 
            P.append((1 + i) * P[n])
            years += 1
        else:
            print(P)
            return years
print(my_saving_plan(1000, 0.07, 2000))
```

Your code had: `P.append((1+i)*P[n-1])`.

The expression: `P[n-1]` on the first iteration has `n == 0`, so `n-1` is `-1` which refers to the last element, which is the same as the first element since there is only one element `P0`.

Each subsequent iteration (where n is 1...) then refers to the previous element, so you end up calculating each value twice.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was looking to much at the formula and not at what the algorithm was doing.

Comment: Just to clarify why I said you had added spaces around the wrong operator: PEP 8 [does recommend different spacings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations), adding spaces around the other one. For example it calls `(a+b) * (a-b)` correct and `(a + b) * (a - b)` wrong (examples taken from there, so you can ctrl-f them to find this there).

Answer (score 1):

Using a while loop you can just keep track of the current value of the savings and in each step compare if the current value already reached the goal:

```
def my_saving_plan(P0, i, goal):
    current_value = P0
    P = [P0]
    years = 0
    while current_value < goal:
        years += 1
        current_value *= (1 + i)
        P.append(current_value)
    print(P)
    
    return years
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all this, why not use the formula to calculate the time it takes for a value to reach another with compound interest rate?

The problem can be expressed as: `A x (1+e)^t = B` and we want to find `t`. So, `t = log(B/A) / log(1+e)`

```
import math
B = 2000
A = 1000
e = 0.07
out = math.ceil(math.log(B/A) / math.log(1+e))
```

Output:

```
11
```

Comment: That's cheating :-D

Comment: The assignment was supposed to be done with iteration, but thanks!

Comment: Meh, too much code. `math.log(B/A, 1+e)`

Answer (score 1):

Why you compute each value twice:

You insert P0 only once, but you **use** it **twice**. You use `P[n-1]`, which in the first loop is `P[-1]`. Python lists support negative indexes, index `-1` gives you the last element, which is the value P0. In the second loop you use `P[0]`, using the same element again (just using a different index). After that, you don't use the same **element** twice again, but you've appended the same **value** twice, so those two equal values will make you append two equal values. Which in turn will make you append two more equal values. Etc.

Comment: Thank you, I completely understand it now!